# Enumeration of primes

Tags: combinatorics, prime-numbers

Given a prime number $p$, there is an associated number $n(p)$, giving its ranking in the sense that $n(2)=1$, $n(3)=2$, $n(5)=3$ etc. Is there a closed form expression for $n(p)$ in terms of $p$?

Comment: I don't think so, since that would require primes to be calculable through a closed-form expression too.

Comment: $n(p)\approx\frac{p}{\ln(p)}$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that I have established a long time ago.

It illustrates the fact that one can easily establish such formula.

The real challenge is to establish a formula which is not "computationally worthless".

---

First, here is a formula which determines whether or not $x$ is prime:

$$f(x)=\left\lfloor\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{k=2}^{x-1}\left\lceil\frac{{x}\bmod{k}}{x}\right\rceil\right)+2\cdot\left\lceil\frac{x-1}{x}\right\rceil}{x}\right\rfloor$$

---

Second, here is a formula which counts the number of primes $\leq x$:

$$g(x)=\sum\limits_{k=2}^{x}f(k)$$

---

Finally, here is the complete formula:

$$n(p)=\sum\limits_{x=2}^{p}\left\lfloor\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{k=2}^{x-1}\left\lceil\frac{{x}\bmod{k}}{x}\right\rceil\right)+2\cdot\left\lceil\frac{x-1}{x}\right\rceil}{x}\right\rfloor$$

Comment: I think you want $g(x) = \sum_{k=2}^x f(k)$, instead of summing $f(x)$.

Comment: @Shagnik: Sorry, I do not understand your comment.

Comment: In your definition of $g(x)$, you have $g(x) = \sum_{k=2}^x f(x) = (x-1) f(x)$, so it is $x-1$ if $x$ is prime, and $0$ if $x$ is composite.  $g(x) = \sum_{k=2}^x f(k)$ would instead count the primes $p \le x$.

Comment: @Shagnik: I still don't understand a single thing of what you're trying to say. I wrote $g(x)=\sum\limits_{k=2}^{x}f(x)$ in my answer. How did you get to $(x-1)f(x)$???

Comment: I don't understand how this is not clear. :-)  I think the mistake you're making is a typo, not a mathematical error - the $x$ inside the function should be a $k$, since you are summing over $k$.  What you want is $f(2) + f(3) + f(4) + ... + f(x)$, which is $\sum_{k=2}^x f(k)$.

Comment: @Shagnik: Damn, that's right... Thank you for pointing it out :)

Comment: No problem!  Sorry for not being clearer from the start. :)

Comment: @Shagnik: BTW, it has no effect on the bottom line, which doesn't make any use of $g(x)$ to begin with.

Comment: beautiful formula! you are a genius man. i nominate you for the abel and fields prize!

Comment: Yes, the bottom line is fine, since $x$ is the index of summation here.  Note that you can simplify your formula a bit: $\lceil \frac{x-1}{x} \rceil$ is always $1$ when $x \ge 2$, so you can get rid of those expressions.

Comment: @MrCrazy: Thanks :) ... Though, please read the first paragraph of my answer, there's nothing too genius about the formula I'm afraid.

Comment: @Shagnik: I know, but I wanted to avoid being told that $f(1)=2$, meaning that $1$ is (possibly) prime. For $n(p)$, since the summation starts from $2$ (and since the domain is only the set of prime numbers anyway), the part of $\left\lceil\frac{x-1}{x}\right\rceil$ is indeed redundant.

Comment: You could also use $f(x)=\prod_{ k=2 }^{ x - 1 }{ \left\lceil{ \frac{x \bmod k}{ k } }\right\rceil}$. Since $x \bmod k = 0$ when $x$ is divisible by $k$, $f(x)=0$, otherwise just multiplying by $1$, because $0 < \frac{x \bmod k}{ k } < 1$ when $x$ is not divisible by $k$.

Answer (score 2):

Well I don't think there is any "nice" closed form in the sense that you can evaluate it easily in term of standard functions. But you can write :
$$
n(p) = \pi(p)
$$
Where $\pi(n)$ is the [Prime-counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function)
(Note that we have the famous result $x/ln(x) \sim \pi(x)$ )